# Using Google API for Python- no option to download credentials.json file?

Tags: python, json, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

But when I try and create credentials, there's no option to download the associated json file:

[image]

How do I get my hands on the `credentials.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

I think that from your image, you are trying to retrieve the file from API key. When you want to use the JSON file of the credential at the Quickstart, please retrieve the file from "OAuth 2.0 client IDs". The flow for retrieving it is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Select "OAuth client ID" at "Create credentials".

   - [image]
2. Select "Other" as "Application type", and input name. Then, click "Create". I think that you can also use "Web application".

By this flow, you can see the download button as follows. When you click the button, you can download the credential file. This can be used for the Quickstart script.

[image]

#### References:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)- [Create a client ID and client secret](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#webapp)

  - You can also see the document for creating " OAuth client ID" here.

If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks lots!! That did the trick. Wish they explained this in the documentation.

Comment: @Reid Pryzant Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. I thought so too.